# Managing hibernate session in servlet side of a GWT application

Tags: hibernate, session, gwt

I'm using hibernate in a GWT application where I've a separate client/service/business/dao layer.

The service/business layer uses the dao layer to fetch/update models used for request handling. The issue is, I'm following the anti-pattern of opening/closing hibernate sessions inside DOA class methods.

The general hibernate guidelines seems to suggest that, we should have a request scoped session. This could be done in several places like servlet filter, or the service layer. We can open the session and inject it to the DAO layer and close it out in the service layer before finishing up the request.

I was wondering if someone has any working code/example that illustrates any standard approach to deal with this.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

All GWT requests use also the servlet mechanism, you have it in your web.xml. You can create your own CustomRequestFactoryServlet that will extend from the GWT standard servlet and do the session injection to your (common baseclassed service) and clean session closing too.

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>requestFactory</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>nsa.snowden.CustomRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>requestFactory</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```